# how to hide rdlc word and excel option from rdlc

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

how to hide Word and excel option in RDLC Report please anyone .. help me this i am searching 3 hours but not success
Please help me this i want only PDF not word and excel how do this

```
protected void ReportViewer1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisableUnwantedExportFormat(ReportViewer1, "Excel");
            DisableUnwantedExportFormat(ReportViewer1, "Word");
        }
        public void DisableUnwantedExportFormat(ReportViewer ReportViewerID, string strFormatName)
        {
            FieldInfo info;
            foreach (RenderingExtension extension in ReportViewerID.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions())
            {
                if (extension.Name.Trim().ToUpper() == strFormatName.Trim().ToUpper())
                {
                    info = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    info.SetValue(extension, false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You posted some code, but haven't described what efforts you went through to debug it. Did you check what is returned by `ReportViewerID.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()`? Do your names match? Do you get an exception?

Comment: yes everything is match but its not working